# Reports PHPUnit ZendFramework

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, netbeans, phpunit

I'm running phpunit tests with zendframework using netbeans but the reports are not being generated. The folder was created however no reports.

My directoty struture:

```
-application
--models
--modules
-library
-log
--report
-bootstrap.php
-phpunit.xml
```

phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
<testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
    <directory>./application</directory>
</testsuite>
<testsuite name="Library Test Suite">
    <directory>./library</directory>
</testsuite>

<filter>
    <!-- If Zend Framework is inside your project's library, uncomment this filter -->
    <!-- 
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../../library/Zend</directory>
    </whitelist>
    -->
</filter>

<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/report" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight = "true" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80" />
    <log type="testdox" target="./log/testdox.html" />
</logging>
```

The tests are running correctly but How should I configure my phpunit.xml to generate the reports?

My PHPUnit version is 3.5.15

Comment: Do you have all dependencies of phpunit installed?

Comment: For which reports are you asking? *Code Coverage Reports*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, I tried running from terminal. It was throwing a memory exception, I increased php memory limit and works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, too, and if i remember correctly it had something to do with xdebug (or similar) not running - but in my case the command line tool has thrown some error.